# Stored procedure to validate if values exist

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I would like my stored procedure-that deletes and inserts new data from a staging table (1 to 1)-  to check if the latest data has values "HEB" and "Kroger" for the column "Provider" before executing.

There might be more than these values for the column "Provider" but that's OK (so it's ok if there's values "HEB", Kroger", and "Walmart" because it contains Kroger and HEB). I want this data validation to happen so that the data from the staging table is not added if the providers don't INCLUDE "HEB" and "KROGER".

This is what I have so far, but it fails due to the fact that there are more providers other than HEB and Kroger.

Any help is appreciated! thanks.

```
BEGIN
SELECT count(distinct(provider)) as count_provider FROM GroceryStore
where collection_Date = (select max(collection_date) from GroceryStore)
and provider = "HEB" or provider = "Kroger";

if (count_provider = 2) then 
  
delete from target_table where 1=1;
insert into target_table(select * from GroceryStore);
  
#insert data into log table
   insert into Log_Table (select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as updated_timestamp,
 "GroceryStoreProcessing" as procedure_name, "Success" as log_message);
  
  --insert data into data refresh table
delete from `last_refresh` where 1=1;
 insert into  `last_refresh` (select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as updated_timestamp) ;

else 
  --insert log for incomplete results - canceled import
  #insert data into log table
   insert into log_table (select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as updated_timestamp,
 "GroceryStoreProcessing" as procedure_name, "Failed" as log_message);
    return;
End if;
END
```

```html
--sample source table

date   provider 
----------------
11-17-20  Kroger
11-17-20  HEB
11-17-20  Walmart
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `count(distinct provider)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Please only tag the relevant RDBMS.

Comment: @DaleK My question is about an IF statement which is used with Oracle and SQL server and Big Query.

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess as to what you want.

```
DECLARE @collection_date_max date -- use the matching datatype here
SELECT @collection_date_max = max(collection_date) from GroceryStore

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM GroceryStore 
        WHERE collection_Date = @collection_date_max AND [provider] = 'HEB')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM GroceryStore 
        WHERE collection_Date = @collection_date_max AND [provider] = 'Kroger')
BEGIN

    delete target_table

    insert target_table
    select * 
    from GroceryStore

    insert into Log_Table(updated_timestamp, [procedure_name], log_message)
    values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'GroceryStoreProcessing', 'Success')

    ...

END ELSE BEGIN -- cancel import

END
```

I just noticed your response about being ORACLE.  I'm SQL Server centric, but I'm sure the EXISTS will translate.